# C# insertion sort after each value

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, insertion-sort

How can I run the Insertion Sort code after each time user enters a value. Please notice that I don't have much knowledge about programming so showing an example or ready to use code would be appreciated.

```
    Console.Write("How long the Insertion sort list should be?: ");
    var countString = Console.ReadLine();
    int count = Convert.ToInt32(countString);
    int[] data = new int[count];

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {

        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        data[i] = Convert.ToInt32(input);

        Console.WriteLine(input); // << HERE THE SORTING SHOULD HAPPEN AFTER EACH VALUE THAT I ADD.

    }


    int j = 0;
    int help = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < data.Length; i++) 
    {
        j = i;
        help = data[i];

        while (j > 0 && help < data[j - 1])
        {
            data[j] = data[j - 1];
            j--;
        }

        data[j] = help;
    }

    foreach (var i in data)
    {
        Console.Write("{0}, ", i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Write out what needs to happen in English first before trying to code it.  When you have a new item to add what are the various steps that need to take place?  Write out an example on a piece of paper what the array should look like and how it should be altered on each iteration of the loop.  Once you know what needs to be done you can either code each step on it's own (rather than trying to find an answer to the whole thing) or look up how to do each individual step, to which there will most certainly be existing resources to help you.

Comment: This provides a good explanation:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12377745/insertion-sort-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can visually divide your code into two parts. The first part is for inserting the values. The second part sorts these values. So you have to cut the second part and insert at the place, where sorting should happen, I hope you will find this place ;)

Also think that you should replace `i` in the second `for` with something else, for example with `k`

Good luck